# How can I Load balance or make two WiFi adapter connections fail-over to the same network?

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, load-balancer

I have two WiFi adapters in my laptop, and both of them connected to my home network:

[image]

Now, I thought that when adapter one loses connectivity, the connection of adapter two will be used.. but that is not the case. My laptop keeps saying limited coonnectivity on adapter #1, while on adapter #2 there is internet.. then I go to the web browser and I see "cannot connect to the internet". This means that the second WiFi connection isn't used at all? I tried bridging the two adapters but the result is the same.

How can I configure my laptop to use #2 if I have limited connectivity on #1 and vice-versa? And if it's possible, how to load balance both connections for a better total signal strenght?

I'm using Windows 8.

Comment: You title refers to load balancing, yet you seem to be asking about fail-over in your question.

Comment: @gizmo http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/41866-42-build-home-network-wifi-connections

Answer (score 0):

Under 'View Network Connections' try selecting both of the wireless connections and right clicking and selecting 'bridge connections'. That might do what you are looking for.

Comment: " I tried bridging the two adapters but the result is the same." :) 
And welcome to SuperUser! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to "load balance" and use two sources/connections to increase bandwidth/data rate.  If that's what you're shooting for, in my experience, you're not able to with standard windows. It seems like your laptop connected to your wifi, reconnected as a "new" connection, maybe there was a change from public to private... but I believe one may be a virtual connection, and not a physical connection.  If you're comfortable removing the back panel* and/or the warranty isn't a concern, check to see if there is two wifi modules.  If there isn't, you're next step would probably be software.